# I don't have ListView in toolbox, intellisense, and doens't work in code

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am using ASP.NET v3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.  For some reason ListView doesn't appear in my toolbox, it doesn't show up in intellisense when coding, and if I try to include one anyways I can't access it from code behind (will give error saying it isn't declared).  What am I missing here.... where is my listview!?

Update: I have v3.5 installed but for some reason the project is using 2.0... now on to figure out how to change that.  In my project references several things say version 3.5.0.0 and several say 2.0.0.0 .... is there any way to update everything to version 3.5 ???

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your project's TargetFramework to 2.0 and follow VS.NET's instructions to reload project.  Then change the TargetFramework back to 3.5 and follow instructions.

It worked for me to get the asp:ListView back into intellisense.

Not sure what gets VS.NET in this state though.

Answer (score 0):

Does your project reference `System.Web.Extensions`?  You will need to do so to get at the new `ListView` control.

Comment: I just found out if I try System.Environment.Version.ToString() it says I'm using version 2.0.  In my project's references tho, several things are 3.5 and several are 2.0.  System.Web.Extensions is listed as 3.5.0.0 though... is there any way to update everything to 3.5?

Comment: `System.Environment.Version` is the version of the runtime, not the version of ASP.NET.  ASP.NET 3.5 still uses version 2.0 of the CLR so you should be fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a FQ assembly reference to the 3.5 version of `System.Web.Extensions`, in the  web.config section.

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Also make sure you have a FQ assembly reference in the `<system.web><compilation><assemblies>` web.config section too.